# What should be covered in a UI Standards document?

Tags: design-process, documentation

I'm a coop student who is creating a web/desktop application design standards document for a company I'm working at. Each standard in the document needs to be supported by a reputable source.

**What are some reputable sources for design standards that I could use?**

Sources I am currently using are:

- textbooks
- blogs from active web designers
- a book, and
- a few purchased university class notes from design courses.

The document needs to cover all aspects of application design (and the design process) for websites accessed from any device (laptop, mobile, etc...).

Comment: While I appreciate your position, I can't see what the specific question is in your post.  Ask something clear and you will get answers, but if your question is "how do I do this big job with all its details", you aren't going to get much.

Comment: Haha fair enough, I went through and edited it now and tried to make it more specific.

Comment: Still rather broad.  If someone answers on one section and someone else on another, how do you use votes to let someone else reading the question know which is the better answer?  Try keeping it to one specific question, otherwise it is more like a "please do my work" sort of question.

Comment: I edited the question down to be more answerable. Your question is really about wanting to find out sources for your document. We can help you with that without needing to see an outline of the document itself. I recommend asking a separate question if you want advice on what to include in the document itself.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I'm pretty new at this so I'm just figuring out how to phrase questions properly

Answer (score 1):

You might find the Microsoft User Experience Interaction Guidelines useful for some of this:

Its rather a large pdf downloadable from this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511258.aspx